# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, visual-studio, razor

I'm trying to convert a list to DataSet but it seems that the table has a relationship and not let me go

> This is the code I try convert List to DataSet

```
public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Type elementType = typeof(T);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(t);

        //add a column to table for each public property on T
        foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
        {
            Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;

            t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);
        }

        //go through each property on T and add each value to the table
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = t.NewRow();
```

> Here says targetinvocationexception was unhandled by user code

```
            foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
            {
                row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value; 



            }

            t.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: I Suppose T is some Context object from EF?

Comment: This error usually means you're trying to read a navigation property outside of the DbContext it was loaded. You need to include all navigation properties when pulling in the data if you want to transport this object intact.

Comment: Use try catch and find out what inner exception says

Comment: Invariably, this is because you're wrapping your data access (EF context instantiation, etc.) in a `using` block. You should *never* do this. Your context should be request-scoped. You can handle that simply by making it a field on your controller, but it's better to inject it, instead, using the DI container of your choice.